# Put a table at the top of a Google Docs document with a script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api

I must be missing something obvious here - but how do you add a table to the top of a document using Google Apps Script. I know that this:

```
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var top = doc.getBody().getChild(0);
top.asParagraph().insertText(0, data);
```

Puts my variable (in this case 'data') at the top of the document - but I cannot seem to do anything there with append.table at this location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert a table, use the [`insertTable`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#inserttablechildindex)  method of the Body object.

```
function insertTable() {  
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  doc.getBody().insertTable(0, [['This', 'is'], ['my', 'table']]);
}
```

The first argument is the index of the table:  0 = beginning of document.